# PowerShell: Remove text from $result variable

Tags: powershell, text, replace

I need to remove the `(UTC-07:00)` from `$result`. How can this be done?

```
$Result = '(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)'
```

Comment: Please show in code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-replace` regex operator:

```
$Result = '(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)'

$TimeZoneName = $Result -replace '^\(UTC[+-][01][0-9]:[0134][05]\)\s*'
```

The regular expression pattern used describes:

```
^                      # start of string
\(                     # a literal `(`
UTC                    # the string `UTC`
[+-]                   # a `+` or a `-`
[01][0-9]:[0134][05]   # a HH:mm timestamp
\)                     # a literal `)`
\s*                    # 0 or more whitespace characters
```

The expression used for the timestamp (`[01][0-9]:[0134][05]`) might look a bit strange, but time zone offsets are always in 15 minute increments so we only need to match `00`, `15`, `30` and `45` as the `mm` part.

As a result, the string value stored in `$TimeZoneName` is now `"Mountain Time (US & Canada)"`